# OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: setup user: invalid argument: unknown

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, sudo

I am trying to access host machine (ubuntu) folder within docker container (both to read and write from the container during my development). So what I am trying is, getting the host machine folder owner's userid & groupid and creating the same user within the docker container, but I keep getting this error when I try to build the image, I am using rootless docker container though.

Here is my dockerfile,

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.1.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu18.04

ARG NB_USER="jovyan"
ARG NB_UID="312349448"  #Userid for the host user
ARG NB_GID="1611487162" #Groupid for the host user
ENV HOME /home/${NB_USER}


ENV PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
ENV PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3


RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && update-ca-certificates 


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    tar \
    wget \
    bash \
    rsync \
    gcc \
    curl \ 
    wget \
    htop \
    git \
    gcc \
    sudo \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libhdf5-serial-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzmq3-dev \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip

RUN apt-get update && \
    useradd -l -m -s /bin/zsh -N -u "${NB_UID}" "${NB_USER}" && \
    echo "${NB_USER} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers


USER ${NB_UID}
WORKDIR /home/jovyan
RUN sudo chown -R ${NB_UID}:${NB_GID} /home/jovyan

# Jupyter lab & other python packages
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir awscli \
    pyspark \
    notebook==5.* \
    numpy \
    pandas \
    jupyterlab \
    jupyter-dash \
    jupytext \
    nbresuse \
    ipywidgets 


# Kubeflow specific stuff
ENV NB_PREFIX /

# COPY run.sh /run.sh
# RUN sudo chmod +x /run.sh
# CMD ["/run.sh"]
CMD ["jupyter", "lab","--notebook-dir=/home/jovyan","--ip=0.0.0.0","--allow-root","--no-browser","--port=8888","--ServerApp.token=''","--ServerApp.password=''"]
```

This is the error I am getting, I can roughly say its related to user, but dont know why this is happening and what to do,

```
Step 19/23 : RUN sudo chown -R ${NB_UID}:${NB_GID} /home/jovyan
 ---> Running in 10f8a668bcc1
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: setup user: invalid argument: unknown
```

Comment: You don't usually need `sudo` in Docker at all; use `USER root` if you need to become root.  I'd similarly remove the `/etc/sudoers` setup that gives your "unprivileged" user unrestricted permissions provided they remember to ask nicely first.